# CiviXero - what's the status?

Tags: extension, accounting

I'm looking to hear from users of Eileen's excellent CiviXero extension!

1) Do you have any active bugs with CiviXero? Instances of data not being updated in Xero or Civi when they should be?

2) Is there anything that you need CiviXero to do which it currently can't?

3) Any problems associated with high volumes of transactions?

4) Does anyone know 100% for sure that it works with Membership purchases and renewals?

5) Does this work on a "batch" system for insertion and retrieval? (I see nz.co.fuzion.civixero/CRM/Civixero/Job/job.mgd.php, usually for scheduled jobs right?). If so, are there throttling settings (I can't see any in nz.co.fuzion.civixero/settings/Civixero.setting.php)?

Thanks - I really do appreciate all responses!

Comment: Hey John. hopefully Eileen will get to comment here but is out of the country at present.

Comment: Thanks pal :) - stack exchange doesn't let me just reply with "Thanks pal :)"

Comment: no it doesn't - do you want to flick me an email so i can reply with some other xero comments directly?

Comment: @JohnFF: StackExchange is designed to have a single question per 'question' so that answers can be voted on and the best one selected. Could you rephrase or post into the old forum?

Answer (score 0):

The Issue list for the extension is at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/issues and is the logical place for 1) bug reports, 2) feature requests, 3) bug reports re: performance, 4) feature requests/bug reports re membership purchases. You can probably also use that issue queue to ask 5) about how it is implemented, or even better, offer to update the documentation if provided with that answer.